# Creating a bent line shape drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I want to underline a `TextView` with a bent line, like this:

[image]

I thought a background drawable would be right for this but I can't figure out how to achieve that. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: you can create a 9 patch drawble like this and can set this as the background of your textview

Comment: That was actually the easiest method, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create that background either with a `9-patch` image from an image created with your favorite image editor(and it should be pretty easy to do it) or creating a xml drawable. To create that type of drawable in xml you would use a `ClipDrawable` that will clip another `Shape` drawable. So you will have:

**background.xml**(this will be the background of the `TextView`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/background_shape"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

and the **background_shape.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Then in your activity, you would get the background drawable for that `TextView` and set its level:

```
ClipDrawable clip = (ClipDrawable) findViewById(R.id.textView1).getBackground();
clip.setLevel(5000);
```

You can teak the look of the drawable by playing with the corners radius, padding and the level of the `ClipDrawable`.

I don't know if you'll be able to obtain the exact image with the xml drawable.

Answer (score -1):

**shape.xml**  (Save this file in drawables)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000"/>    <!-- This is the Border Color For TextView-->
<!-- "#5D2E8C"  -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />   <!-- background to the TextView -->
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

**Now, Set the background property for TextView like this::**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
/>
```